# Install and run Linux on partition of external HD?

Tags: install, partition, unix

Is it possible to install and run Linux on a partition an external HD in OS X?

Almost all the instructions I've found are about installing to the entire external HD, not to a partition.

I've install *rEFInd* on a Core2 Duo late 2007 iMac and dd'd a Linux .iso to a FAT-formatted partition on an external FW 800-connected drive, but the drive disappears from Finder and does not appear as an option in *rEFInd* when the iMac is rebooted.

I have to change the partition format back to OSX Extended (journaled) via selecting *Disk -> Partition -> click on the particular partition* in OS X 10.11.6 Disk Utility, and rename it to see it again, which of course wipes out the dd'd .iso. Duh!

Any ideas or is running Linux from an external HD partition impossible?

Answer (score -2):

I think it is possible but you must partition/erase that partition as bootable.